# C# Checkbox not gaining focus on Tabstop

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, tabindex, tabstop

I am making a config editor form and have hit a bit of an issue, I put a lot of time into userfriendly and efficient design and therefor want the `TabIndex` to work perfectly to minimize use of mouse.

My problem is now when I try to tab through the controls I noticed the `CheckBox` was not gaining focus like if you press it with the mouse, this means I couldn't tab through and change their state directly from keyboard.

How do I make the `CheckBox` gain focus via `TabIndex` and `TabStop` so that I can just press Enter to change its state via the KeyUp event.

Below is a picture of my form, and next to it a picture of the `TabIndex` as well as a the code taken directly from the `Form.Designer.cs` class.

[image]

```
        // 
        // cbxDefaultPublic
        // 
        this.cbxDefaultPublic.AutoSize = true;
        this.cbxDefaultPublic.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(247, 12);
        this.cbxDefaultPublic.Name = "cbxDefaultPublic";
        this.cbxDefaultPublic.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(15, 14);
        this.cbxDefaultPublic.TabIndex = 1;
        this.cbxDefaultPublic.TabStop = true;
        this.cbxDefaultPublic.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

Please note that I had a hard time explaining this cause its a bit complicated and didn't know how to explain it so bare over with me if I got a few things wrong.

Comment: The CheckBox control prefers to have Text in order to show the focus.

Comment: @GrantWinney Ok now I'm really confused, mostly cause the `SpaceBar` works, but what confuses me is that the visuals for the `CheckBox` doesn't change when it's in focus, like how controls (fx Buttons) turn slightly blue when they get focus.

Comment: @LarsTech I tested it with text, it seems the `CheckBox` stays gray while the text on it will have a dotted outline.

Comment: That's just the way the CheckBox was designed.

Comment: @GrantWinney What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the `CheckBox` change to the LightBlue as if you hover your mouse over it just like when buttons are in focus.

Comment: If you don't want to use text with the CheckBox, check out GotFocus event to change the appearance when it's focused, so you know it's focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the people commenting on my question I was able to get on the right track of what to do and what to search for.
Thanks to Grant Winney, LarsTech and JohnnyBoy for explaining to me how the `CheckBox` worked and what I needed to look at.

I found out that the `CheckBox` does not have a public highlight feature so I had to get creative.
What I did was I created a custom `CheckBox` and well.. might just show you the code :P

```
public class MyCbx : CheckBox {
    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
        base.OnEnter(e);
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    }
    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
        base.OnLeave(e);
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e) {
        if(!this.Focused) {//prevent it from losing highligh if control is in focus
            base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        }
    }
}
```

So I call the MouseEnter and Leave events when It gain or lose focus, this will make it change to a highlighted state.